# Confusion on CRISIL Rating

Tags: mutual-funds, nse-india, credit-rating-agency, bse-india

Which is better CRISIL 5 or CRISIL 1. Problem arises when PAYTM MONEY shows under top rated funds with CRISIL 5...but CRISIL rates funds 1 to 5, 1 being the best performer.
I am confused?

Comment: You might consider adding a country tag and also perhaps mentioning the country in the text of your question. -1 pending edits

Comment: Country Tags Added.

Comment: You might want to add a source for "_CRISIL rates funds 1 to 5_"... according to [Credit Rating Scale](https://www.crisil.com/en/home/our-businesses/ratings/credit-ratings-scale.html) on CRISIL's site, they use a number of scales (AAA, A, etc.; A1, A2, etc.) but not a "star rating". My _guess_ is PAYTM just convert whatever rating CRISIL give to a particular fund into a "star rating" from 1 (worst) to 5 (best).